# BIRT - How to insert the data from different rows of one dataset into one dynamic text?

Tags: database, birt

Let's say if I have the following dataset:

```
firstname     surname     role       title
John          Doe         Father     Mr.
Jane          Doe         Mother     Mrs.
Janie         Doe         Child      Miss
```

I want to create a dynamic text containing the following sentence:

```
Genetic relationship between Mr. John Doe, Mrs. Jane Doe and Miss Janie Doe is...
```

What I know is that I can use `<VALUE-OF>row["title"]</VALUE-OF>&nbsp;<VALUE-OF>row["firstname"]</VALUE-OF>&nbsp;<VALUE-OF>row["surname"]</VALUE-OF>` if I have one person, but I don't know how to specify the information for three people in the expected order?

Answer (score 1):

For a start, you need to add a group based on surname.
You can then use the CONCATENATE aggregate to concatenate the names with an expression like this:

```
row["title"] + " " + row["firstname"]+ " " + row["surname"]
```

and something like ", " as the delimiter.

On output, you have to replace the last ", " with " and " using Javascript.

The output has to be in the group header or group footer row.